# How do I get Twitter feeds (only content) for my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

How do I get Twitter feeds (only normal text) for use on my website, similar to those shown in the image below?

[image: Twitter feed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for it.

http://sonnyt.com/Tweetie/

Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `twitterFetcher.js` for this. And you can find further information and example usage in this site:
https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher

Comment: Hi @kkakkurt, Thank you for your answer, can you please check below link.

output -  http://zeebracross.biz/projects/zc/twitter.html
need similar to  - http://zeebracross.biz/projects/zc/twitter-2.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use twitterFetcher's "customCallback" option for this. It was described as "config5" in this link: https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher/blob/master/js/exampleUsage.js  You can adjust it by your html and css values.

Comment: thank you. it work good, but i need something else. 

really i like your script. once again thank you for your support.